# Selecting part of a single entity without retrieving the entire entity

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to get a single property(blob) from a single entity (by Id).  I have:

```
context.References
    .Single(r => r.ID == id)
    .Blob;
```

This strikes me as inefficient, because I'm getting the entire Reference, only to discard everything except the Blob.  This led to

```
context.References
    .Where(r => r.ID == id)
    .Select(r => r.Blob)
    .Single();
```

Which should only query for the Blob, but having the Single as an afterthought at the end is somewhat annoying (yet enforcing the singularity I feel is necessary).  My question is this: is there a better way to accomplish this, or is my second codeblock just the way it is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that's the way it is.  Running your queries in LINQPad shows that Entity Framework translates the queries to this:

```
SELECT TOP (2) 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Blob] AS [Blob], 
... etc for all columns
FROM [dbo].[References] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[Id]
```

and

```
SELECT TOP (2) 
[Extent1].[Blob] AS [Blob]
FROM [dbo].[References] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[Id]
```

So you're correct that the second query is *slightly* more efficient.  Whether this is significant is something for you to test and decide.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `context.References.Single(r => r.ID == id).Blob` to combine the Where and the Single, but that will transfer the whole entity. For efficiency sake your solution is best.